# How to restart openvpn setup on amazon AWS turnkey linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, turnkey-linux

I installed TKL AMI on my AWS EC2 pool, and the first time I logged in, it showed me the setup screen, which I dismissed since I had to do some other config first.

However, when I logged out and logged back in, the setup program no longer launches! Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

`# turnkey-init` worked :). Posting here so someone can find it if Googling.